Cloud Run DirectPath is misconfigured. Please set the EnableDirectPath option along with the EnableDirectPathXds option error message
Colleagues,
I am a new user to Google Cloud Run. I have a Docker Image that generates data for a future AI project. The image runs on Cloud Run without difficulty. I am trying to mount a Cloud Storage bucket to the image for read and write access. When I try to read from the bucket, I get an error that halts execution.
File "/app/./Pedigree_Generator.py", line 77, in . f = open("/mnt/gcs-1:pedigree-bucket/data/test.txt","r").,FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/gcs-1:pedigree-bucket/data/test.txt'
I am running the container as a Job. I am mounting a Cloud Storage bucket "gcs-1" to the image with the a mount path "/data." I have uploaded a file "test.txt" to the bucket and am trying to open it with the Python Open statement that is shown above.
Going through the logs, I see warning messages that may indicate the problem:
"Cloud Storage FUSE will be mounted to an internal path not accessible from customer containers." AND
"WARNING: DirectPath is misconfigured. Please set the EnableDirectPath option along with the EnableDirectPathXds option."
Note that when I run the image on my local machine, and when I run it in Cloud Run, without mounting a volume, it works fine and doesn't generate any errors or warnings.
It is apparent that I am erroneously setting up the storage bucket mount and mounting pathway. Can anyone suggest a way to do this that will work and avoid the DirectPath errors that i am getting?
I appreciate your help...

Have a look at this GitHub which might help

Thank you. This does provide insight. It brings up a question: is there a Google CLI command that I could run that would mount volume, without the error. Please bear in mind that I am a beginner...

check this document on Mount a Cloud Storage volume
